# .click() does not work on a span class that loaded later

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my main page I have a "music" button, it loads music.txt

**script.js**

```
$("#music").load("music.txt");
$('.song').click(function () {  ... });
```

**music.txt**:

```
 <span class="song"> bl </span>
```

`$('.song').click` does not work on `music.txt` (it works on mainpage). I tried `live()` and `delegate()` as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `.on()` jQuery method.

```
$('.song').on('click',function () { /*...*/ });
```

**OR**

```
$(document).on('click','.song',function(){ /*...*/ });
```

because `.live()` is deprecated from newer version.

In first example the `.on()` method behaves similar to `bind` and will only work on elements that **already exist**.

The second example behaves like `.live()` or `delegate()` in many ways. And will work for elements **that are added later.**

Comment: Yes sir!  `.on()` replaced the old `.live()`.