# jQuery handler - how to apply an action to dynamically added element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Adding an event handler to dynamically created elements can be handled as shown here:

[In jQuery, how to attach events to dynamic html elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/in-jquery-how-to-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements)

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.myclass', function() {
    alert( $(this).text() );
});
```

However say I want to then perform an action on elements that were also added dynamically.

In the sample below $('inout.wp')s are being added after this code has run and I wish to validate them all using [jQuery Validator](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) when the handler fires:

```
<input type="text" name="wp_address_0" placeholder="Enter a Town, City or Postcode" id="wp_address_0" class="geocode wp">

<script>
$('body').on('click', 'a.myclass', function() {
    $('input.wp').valid();
});
</script>
```

I though perhaps I could use .find for this:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.myclass', function() {
    $("#waypoints").find('input.wp').valid();
});
```

But it doesn't help. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It would be helpful to the reader to see the HTML markup of the newly added elements that you want to validate.  Depending on the markup & situation, some might need to use the `rules('add')` method for dynamically added HTML.

Comment: @sparky - the way the automated rules were working wasn't a problem, my problem was simply identifying which elements to apply them to *programatically*.  The submit was working applying the rules correctly but I wanted to recheck validity when the goal posts had been moved.

Comment: My point is that if you show the markup, this would be more clear to _others seeking help_.   There are many different ways to use this plugin.

Comment: @sparky - point taken however I've got multiple addClassRules and custom validation functions so it probably would only serve to confuse in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this was way easier than I thought and I should have realised BEFORE asking...

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.myclass', function() {
    $('#waypoints input.wp').valid();
});
```

As long as you reference a static container for the dynamic elements in the selector they appear to be found.

Answer (score 0):

**Replace**

```
$('body').on(
```

**with**

```
$(document).on(
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216908/click-does-not-work-on-a-span-class-that-loaded-later/15216920#15216920

Comment: for this to solve the problem `body` would be the element which had been added after the binding